# Increase size and spacing of matplotlib figure xaxis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a bar plot with several thousand x axis entries where each xtick is a word. Unfortunately, the words overlap one another. I don't want to make the font any smaller because you already have to zoom in considerably in order to read anything. I increased the size of the plot, but it doesn't appear to change the size of the x axis, instead there are considerable margins.

How can I increase the length of the x axis to allow for better spacing between the ticks?

```
tree = ET.parse('Posts.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
cnt = Counter()

for child in root: 
    if child.get('Tags') and 'pytorch' in child.get('Tags') or child.get('Tags') and 'tensorflow' in child.get('Tags') or child.get('Tags') and 'keras' in child.get('Tags'):
        results = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>', child.get('Tags'))
        for tag in results:
            if tag != 'pytorch' and tag != 'keras' and tag != 'tensorflow':
                cnt[tag] += 1
cnt = {k:v for k,v in cnt.items() if v > 1.0}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cnt, orient='index')
plt.figure()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (150,50)
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.savefig('histogram.png')
```

Comment: A figure of (150,50) inches is massive! I suggest you try something else, like plot only a range of x values but in different figure environments. Or show just a subset of the x labels if they are continuous (it seems like your data is not).

Comment: Addendum, many viewports will not be able to display a figure size that big (for example, Jupyter notebook will just shrink it down for you). If you export, you'll probably have to zoom way in to do anything useful. This might not be the answer you want, but it's the answer you need.

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 is there a max, still useful figsize?

Comment: @FChm is there a way to split up a dataframe into multiple figure environments?

Comment: @Matt I don't know about a max useful figsize. I tend to judge by the size of the expected output. I.e., if you are going to print it you want it no larger than the size of an A4 page (about 8 inches wide). If its for viewing on a monitor it could be larger.

Maybe an A4 page is a good 'rule-of-thumb' as it will be OK for most media (visual inspection, powerpoint slides etc..)

Comment: Generally, I think of the medium someone would use if they were going to print it. IMHO, a screen is s pretty good proxy for a sheet of paper (given how people use it) so I use that standard I personally stick to. Most things are not going to be more than 8*10 (8.5*11 paper with titles and margins). If you are making a poster that's going to hung up on the wall of your office, then something like 150x50 might be appropriate, but for a screen, it'd be difficult to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An imperfect solution, but one I hope demonstrates a way you could do it is the following:

```
num_plots = 10

sample_size = int(df.shape[0] / num_plots)

for i, n in enumerate(np.linspace(0, df.shape[0], num_plots+1, dtype=int)[:-1]):
    fig = plt.figure()
    df.iloc[n:n+sample_size, :].plot(kind='bar')
    # … format your figure here
    plt.savefig('histogram_{}.png'.format(i))
    plt.close()
```

In the above code you decide how many plots you want and then generate the df indices for use in each plot. However, I will **warn you** this will not plot all the data and is not robust! If you want to plot all the data you should edit this to robustly select *all* the data (e.g, by editing the `np.linspace` function call).

Comment: shouldn't stop be `len(df.index)` instead of `df.shape[0]` (which would equal 1 in this case bc the dataframe is word: 50, word2: 10, word3: 6)

Comment: `len(df.index)` and `df.shape[0]` both give you the number of rows.

Comment: Either way, I hope this gives you enough of an idea to adapt it for your own use!

Comment: Oh huh I guess I'm misunderstanding the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html). But regardless, I'm ready to accept - but could you point out which parameter(s) in the linspace call I would need to change? Because right now I don't understand how it doesn't select all the data

Comment: df.shape[0] is preferred because it is a native method of pandas. It is slightly faster, but functionally identical to len(df.index).

Comment: I think it doesn't take all the features because of the rounding error in `sample_size`, when int is called. I guess the better way of doing it is to get `linspace` to define the start indices.